# Unexpected, unexplained laptop crash HP Pavilion g6

Tags: windows-7, laptop, crash, thermal-paste

I have problem with one HP Pavilion G6. After about 3,5 years of use with no OS reinstall or other maintenance I made clean reinstall Win 7 professional N. I also opened laptop and clean fan and also old thermal paste and apply new on 3 components where it was before (CPU, GPU and ?). It is cheap paste but laptop temperatures significantly decreased.

Everything working fine, but suddenly system crash with no warning or BSOD just like when you unplug running laptop without battery. After that if I try to turn laptop on there is screen to choose normal start or safe-mode but when I click on something system doesn't boot and crash again like before. Just after some time when I turn it on, it runs well again.

This happened 3 times in 4 weeks? 2 times during image processing with PS lightroom and third time today during basic use, with some music listening and net browsing.

Does anybody know what could be wrong or how to identify what is wrong?

Comment: Failing hard disk? Anything in the event logs?

Comment: @DavidPostill No I checked hard disk with HDTune with normal scan not quick and everything was OK

Comment: Does HDTune display the SMART status?

Comment: @DavidPostill yes of course, everything OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in big air gap between GPU and heat sink. I used just Thermal paste which is not good enough. So I bought 1.5mm thick Thermal pad from Arctic and now everything seems fine.

I ran GPU stress test with FurMark which caused immediate system shut down after few seconds before problem fix.

Now after fix I run same test for few minutes without any problem. I just cannot run stress test on both GPUs because for some reason FurMark does not detect both. I posted [new question](https://superuser.com/questions/1045781/furmark-does-not-detect-both-graphics-processors) for this issue. I would appreciate when somebody help me with.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is, in essence, a new Windows 7 installation, it might need specific updates or drivers installed.

1. Check for missing or corrupt files using the [System File Checker](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833).
2. Check for any Microsoft Windows 7 update. Note that some MS updates have *caused* problems; see http://www.forbes.com/sites/jasonevangelho/2014/12/13/new-windows-7-patch-is-effectively-malware-disables-graphics-driver-updates-and-windows-defender/, for example.
3. Go to the HP support site (e.g. http://support.hp.com/us-en/product/HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC-series/5048672/model/5078477/drivers/) to get any driver updates for your machine.
4. Check *Device Manager* to see if any devices are improperly installed or missing drivers.